# Imprimir signos basados en una secuencia (fibonacci)

Tags: java, fibonacci, números-primos

De favor pido sugerencias y ayuda en la siguiente serie:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo el código para encontrar los números primos de la base, y los naturales de los exponentes y se que los signos aumentan en base a la secuencia de fibonacci, pero no entiendo como hacer que los signos se impriman según fibonacci usando solo las siguientes estructuras de control: if, while y for.

```
package virtual;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class sucesiones {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 2, n, natural = 0;
        int contFibo = 0, fibo, primero = 0, segundo = 1;
        int signo = 1, contSigno = 0, cambiaSigno = 1;
        int cprimo = 0;
        boolean esPrimo;
        double suma = 0.0;

        do {
            System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de números que desea sumar: ");
            n = lector.nextInt();
        } while (n < 1);

        //Determinar si es primo
        while (natural < n) {
            esPrimo = true;
            num = num + 1;
            for (int div = 2; div < num; div++) {
                if (num % div == 0) {
                    esPrimo = false;
                }
            }
            if (esPrimo == true) {
                cprimo = cprimo + 1;
                if (contFibo == 0 || contFibo == 1) {
                    fibo = contFibo;
                } else {
                        fibo = (primero + segundo);
                        primero = segundo;
                        segundo = fibo;
                }
                natural++;
                System.out.printf("%d(%d^%d)\n", signo, num, natural);
                suma = suma + Math.pow(num, natural) * signo;

               //Control de signos
                contSigno = contSigno + 1;
                if (contSigno == cambiaSigno) {
                    signo = signo * -1;
                    cambiaSigno = fibo + 1;
                    contSigno = 0;
                }
                contFibo = contFibo + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Suma = %f\n", suma);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La función Fibonacci no tiene mucho secreto, y está en 1000 páginas de internet, en java sería algo como esto:

```
private static int fibo(int n){
  if (n == 0) return 0;
  else if (n == 1) return 1;
  else return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2);
}
```

Y ya que estamos en esto, también vamos crear una función para ver si un número es primo (tú mismo algoritmo, pero dentro de una función)

```
private static boolean esPrimo(int num){
   for (int div = 2; div < num; div++) {
       if (num % div == 0) {
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Tu necesitas que el signo siga una secuencia:

- 1 positivo
- 1 negativo
- 2 positivos
- 3 negativos
- etc

Para esto necesitamos

- La función Fibonacci (que está arriba)
- Un contador especial para seguir la secuencia `int fiboCount=1`
- Una variable para el signo `int signo=-1`
- Una variable para guardar el número de Fibonacci `int fibonacci`

```
While
{
  if(fibonacci==0){
    fibonacci = fibo(fiboCount);
    signo = signo * -1;
    fiboCount++;
  }
  fibonacci--;
}
```

- Si fibonacci==0, calculamos nuevamente un número de Fibonacci
- Cambiamos el signo cada vez que calculamos un nuevo número
- Aumentamos el contador de la secuencia.
- Luego en cada iteración disminuimos el número de fibonacci en 1, hasta llegar a cero, que es cuando debemos calcular el número nuevamente

Código completo:

```
package virtual;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class sucesiones {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 2, n, natural = 1;
        int signo = -1;
        double suma = 0.0;
        int fibonacci = 0;
        int fiboCount=1;
 
        do {
            System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de números que desea sumar: ");
            n = lector.nextInt();
        } while (n < 1);

        //Determinar si es primo
        while (natural <= n) {
            num = num + 1;
            if (!esPrimo(num)) continue;
            
            
            if(fibonacci==0){
                fibonacci = fibo(fiboCount);
                signo = signo * -1;
                fiboCount++;
            }
                
            System.out.printf("%d(%d^%d)\n", signo, num, natural);
            suma = suma + Math.pow(num, natural) * signo;
            natural++;
            fibonacci--;
           
            
        }
        System.out.printf("Suma = %f\n", suma);
    }
    
    private static boolean esPrimo(int num){
        for (int div = 2; div < num; div++) {
            if (num % div == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    private static int fibo(int n){
        if (n == 0) return 0;
        else if (n == 1) return 1;
        else return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2);
    }
}
```